# Prevent "half cut" lines when scrolling a textarea

Tags: html, css, textarea

I have a few textareas with a bunch of text within them. However, I get the bottom of the text kinda cut off before scrolling. I tried using `padding` but it just messes the textarea size and does not apply to the content.

I'm not good at explaining so here's an image

[image]

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/5c7DY/) is also a fiddle

Comment: In fact your left example looks better to me because it gives a better visual clue of that there is more text in it.

Comment: Well the scroll would also signify this.

Comment: I don't think CSS has such a concept.. the text inside is not an element.

Comment: I had achieved it some time ago using pure CSS but cannot find the source so I know it's possible. Thanks for the edit though - makes it way more clearer :)

Comment: @JessieStalk Of a textarea?

Comment: Yes, I'm certain of that.

Comment: @JessieStalk Yes, but (1) this is a lot less natural for human eye and is more cognitive load for reasoning about scrolls and relating them to textareas, in contrast to just naturally _seeing_ that something more is there; (2) new interfaces such as tablets and even Office 2013 very stupidly hide the scrolls, so you don't even know that there's a scroll there until you try moving it. In this case the half-cut line is the ONLY visual clue.

Comment: <textarea  rows="10"> is not a solution? It gives the effect if you remove the height from css.

Comment: It's the same if I was to scroll.

Comment: If you don't want it to depend on scrolling, you'll most likely have to use some javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
<textarea rows="10">Lorem ipsum</textarea>
```

and you can use any style except for `height` (copied from your fiddle):

```
textarea {
    background-color: rgb(235, 235, 235);
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 30%;
    /* height: 150px; REMOVED */
    border: 1px solid rgb(201, 201, 201);
    color: gray;
    padding: 20px;
    font-family: 'Lora' !important;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 17px;
    resize: none;
}
```